# I have installed ubuntu 14.04 and when I try to install citrix recevier I am getting ia32-lbs error?

Tags: 14.04

Please give me the detail procedure for installing citrix in the ubuntu

Comment: did you follow any link? If yes, then post it in your question.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CitrixICAClientHowTo. Give that a go and see if it works for you.

Comment: this is a known problem, but fixable by following instructions at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CitrixICAClientHowTo as also noted by @DrakkenWarr